# How to loop all videos in a stacked montage until the duration of the longest video

Tags: linux, loops, video, ffmpeg

My objective is to play a 4 video montage of different duration, and loop all the videos until the duration of the longest video. However I couldn't figure out how to do this.

The duration of each of the inputs is:

- input1 (Duration: 00:00:00.24)
- input2 (Duration: 00:00:01.98)
- input3 (Duration: 00:00:04.02)
- input0 (Duration: 00:00:04.02)

The following code produces a video with duration equal to that of input1:

```sh
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0]drawtext=text='input0':fontsize=20:x=(w-text_w)/2-200:y=(h-text_h)/2-150[v0];
 [1]drawtext=text='input1':fontsize=20:x=(w-text_w)/2-200:y=(h-text_h)/2-150[v1];
 [2]drawtext=text='input2':fontsize=20:x=(w-text_w)/2-200:y=(h-text_h)/2-150[v2];
 [3]drawtext=text='input3':fontsize=20:x=(w-text_w)/2-200:y=(h-text_h)/2-150[v3];
 [v0][v1][v2][v3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0:shortest=1" -y output.mp4
```

One of my confusion is; when i swap the location of `-stream_loop -1` and `-i input0.mp4`, my output video has the duration of input2.

My ffmpeg version is:

```sh
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-0york1~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york1~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My objective is to play a 4 video montage of different duration, and loop all the videos until the duration of the longest video. However I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Add `-stream_loop -1` before each input except the longest input.

> One of my confusion is; when i swap the location of `-stream_loop -1` and `-i input0.mp4`, my output video has the duration of `input2`.

You're using `shortest=1` in xfade. With `-stream_loop -1` before `input0.mp4` the shortest input becomes input2 (Duration: 00:00:01.98).